# Google Chrome asks every time to login

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I open Chrome with my user ( --profile-directory="Default"), it's asking for my google account/password. The other users on my PC don't have this problem.
Also this is happening on my home PC.

Things i've done:

- reinstall Chrome
- reinstall OS
- deleted the "Login Data" and "Login Data-journal" files

Chrome Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit) running On Windows 10 x64

Comment: What Chrome version are you using and what operating system?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new profile?

Comment: @agtoever updated the question

Comment: @Ramhound I will try, but I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Could you try to (please follow each step carefully): 1. Logout of Chrome. 2. [Reset the browser settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en&visit_id=636757046247878802-375686041&rd=1). 3. Remove your Google account from the [Windows password store](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/stored-user-names-and-passwords-windows). 4. From another device, [check your registered devices](https://www.google.com/apps/mydevices) and remove your Windows PC from the device list. 5. Reboot Windows. 6. Start Chrome and login.